# How do I upload a build to iTunes Connect for TestFlight?

Tags: ios, xcode, app-store-connect, testflight

How do I upload my app I made in Xcode to iTunes Connect to invite Beta testers to download it?

I read the documentation and I tried what it said but it never uploaded my app.

Comment: Did you create the app in iTunes connect first? Did you try validate it first in organizer? Dose your bundle identifier match between Xcode and iTunes connect?

Comment: I was also confused by the documentation. Pretty sure their answer is circular:
-In the Test flight beta testing page it says "Upload a build for the app. See _Uploading a Build for an App_."
-In the Uploading a Build page, under Using Xcode it basically tells you to upload it and "For more information, read _Submitting Your App to the Store_"
-In the Submitting your App page, the first things it says is "After you upload a build to iTunes Connect and sufficiently test that build, submit the build to the store using iTunes Connect". 

Wtf

Comment: @EthanFischer agreed. SO > piles of Apple documentation.

Answer (score 106):

If you have a ready app,

1) Choose "generic iOS device" (don't choose any other devices connected or a simulator)

2) Go to Product --> Archive

3) If everything is fine, it should open the archive in the Organizer - there you can change the name of your upload if you wish. When ready click "validate" and then "Submit to App Store".

*) When creating the next version of the archive don't forget to change the version number from 1.0 to something different (it's "Bundle Version" somewhere in supporting files)

Comment: What happens when "validate" is grayed out?

Comment: The "Archive" is grayed out.

Comment: If Archive is disabled you should make sure that you have not selected an iOS simulator but the Generic iOS Device.

Comment: I forgot to click validate, but it's uploading the archive. Is that bad?

Answer (score 26):

As the above answers are bit old and there have been some changes in iTunesConnect. You can follow these steps to upload build for beta testing :

1. Archive the project by clicking Product->Archive(make sure that the device selected is "Generic iOS Device", else the archive option will be disabled)
2. Xcode will take some time to archive the project, after successful archive a window will open (archive window).
3. There will be option "Validate" (it is always recommended to validate a build before uploading to app store). Click on the "Validate" option and if everything is alright you will see a green tick.
4. Next click on the "Submit to App Store" option, it will take some time to upload the build.
5. Once upload is complete login to your [iTunesConnect](https://appstoreconnect.apple.com/login) account. There MyApps ->
   YOUR_APP_NAME.
6. There you will see a option Testflight. Inside that option you will see "iOS Builds". Check if the uploaded build is shown there, if not, don't worry it takes few minutes.
7. Now coming to the adding beta testers part. There are 2 ways ie. either you can add the testers as internal testers or external testers

a) **Internal Testers**

Check this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50155164/2481247). You do not need beta review for adding internal testers.

b) **External Testers**

This requires beta App review. Beta app review takes less time than the actual app review. For submitting for beta app review click on the build no in Testflight->iOS Builds->build no.(something like 1.0)

[image]

Click on the "Add Testers to the build" and follow the steps. Once the app is beta reviewed, invite will be send to the testers automatically(if you choose to). You only need to submit once per build for beta review. Once a build is beta reviewed you can add upto 2000 testers.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I don't see "Archive" under "Product".  XCode 9.4.1

Comment: After step 6, check your email.  You will be notified if there are any issues preventing your app from being made available.  If so, correct the issues and upload the app again.

Answer (score 9):

From the Xcode menu, go to Window, then choose Organizer

[image: Menu]

From there, validate your build, then if it's good, click "Submit to app store."

[image: Submit]

After it goes through, log in to iTunes Connect and you will see your build toward the bottom of the screen

Comment: How long will it take after it says Upload Complete?

Comment: It varies. I've uploaded builds that are available in Connect after ten minutes or so, and some that took an hour or more. (They usually appear immediately, but are not selectable until a period of time has passed)

Comment: Ah mine finally appeared. I was just a little confused since in Xcode it says It's been uploaded but then in iTunes connect it does not.

Answer (score 7):

The following are the steps that are valid as of July, 2019:

1. Change the version number and/or build number for the app in the general properties.
2. Select Generic IOS Device to build.
3. Choose Product/Archive to create an archive of the app.  The Archive Organizer window will appear.
4. Validate the App.
5. Choose Distribute to upload the App.
6. After the app processes, you will get an email.  This usually takes less than an hour.
7. Log in to appstoreconnect.apple.com and select your new build/version.  Then add test groups or individual testers.  You may have to answer the encryption export question, and you will be asked to describe the changes in this new version.  After you hit submit, the app goes to Apple for review.
8. After about a day, Apple will approve your app for distribution and automatically notify your testers (if you selected that option).  Your testers then should go to the Test Flight app on their phones to download the latest version of your app.

Answer (score 3):

Submit your app build to the App Store like normal via Xcode.

Then go into iTunes Connect -> My Apps -> Your App -> then go to the Prerelease tab.

In the Prerelease tab it will show your builds you've uploaded.  There you will see the ability to Submit For Beta App Review.

Once they approve it then you're golden :)

Comment: Do i have to have an app icon?

Answer (score 2):

You need to build - submit your app via Xcode to App Store, make sure you have proper icons embedded, otherwise, xcode will stop and warn you what you need to include for your app.

Then, (create if needed) and login to iTunes Connect, go to my apps, you will see your app. Then you could add testers for beta test, you will get some crash logs if any.