# How can a company invite me to TestFlight?

Tags: ios, app-store-connect, testflight, apple-developer

Slightly programming related, but I cant seem to figure it out. I have an Apple Developer Account and an iTunes Connect account. When the company invities me, all I get is a "XY Ltd.  invited you to join iTunes Connect".

If I log in via the link nothing happens, I get my own iTunes Connect account. I don't seem to able to switch between roles or anything like that. What's the issue here?

The email they sent me:

[image]

Comment: Remove yourself from testers, add again, you will get a mail with redeem code (Open that link in web and not on phone). Use that redeem code.

Comment: in which mail you get the invitation? in your apple dev account mail or in another mail of yours?

Comment: I'm using the same email for everything. I update the question with the email

Comment: Maybe they invited me the wrong way?

Comment: Do you want to test an app via TestFlight or join their development team?

Comment: Have you checked your testflight app? If you've accepted the invite then, you'll get an option to open the app in your testflight app on iPhone/iPad device.

Comment: I'm developing an app for them and want them to test it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are 2 things here:

1) You need to add the tester in users tab in itunes connect(if you want internal testing feature).

Here the user will get a mail from itunesconnect asking them to activate their apple id(the mail id you added in the user section). This is the mail you have attached in the screenshot. Once they activate the id, you will be able to see the user in the "users & roles" tab as registered.

2) After the first step you need to add that tester to the app's testflight section. This step is only after the user activates the account.

Go to the testflight section of the app and add the user there. Remember the user should have minimum Marketer role or else the user won't be shown in testflight. Here the user will get an email from testflight, with a link "VIEW IN TESTFLIGHT", you can either open the link on mobile which will redirect you to the testflight app OR you can open the link on your system browser and enter the code in the testflight app.

You need to do this process only once.

Hope this helps

Comment: The problem is the company I work for wants to test it. Both of us have Apple Developer accounts separately (I'm a freelancer). Do I need to invite them as testers then?

Comment: Thanks I think this is the way to go